# Can I change the value of Value in e.target.value?

Tags: javascript

I have an autocomplete which functions as an employee search field.  When a user searches for a name and chooses one from the results list, the `onBadgeChange` function is triggered.  This function sends the value of `e.target.value` into another `onChange` as `e`. The value of `e.target.value` after selecting a name is the index of the name as it appeared in the results list.  The index of the name as it appears is not useful data.  What I need to get is the employee badge number.  This is done in `onBadgeChange` where the employee badge number is set to `const empBadge`.  I want to then change the value of `e.target.value` to the value of `empBadge`.  Is this possible?

This is my `onBadgeChange`:

```
    const [empBadge, setEmpBadge] = useState(null);

    const onBadgeChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        employees.employees?.map((emp) => {
            setEmpBadge(emp.Badge);
            return console.log(emp.Badge, emp.Name);
        });
        console.log(e.target.value);
        console.log(e.target.textContent);
        console.log(empBadge);
        onChange(e);
    };
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: This is an X/Y problem. You should not change the e.target.value because you should not forward e to onChange. If you do, then set the relevant string in a data attribute of the target
or Instead have a function that takes a string and send the string to that function. It is a code smell what you do there in my opinion

Comment: Ok, so I have done this, but the id is incorrect.  The correct ID is `DocumentOwner`, but `e.target.id` is `DocumentOwner-option-0`